# What is bit-banding?

Tags: embedded, arm

I am reading the [ARM Cortex M3](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.ddi0337i/DDI0337I_cortexm3_r2p1_trm.pdf) reference manual and the concepts "bit-band", "bit-band region" and "bit-band alias" appear.

What is bit-banding?

Comment: I have dedicated a [github page](https://github.com/IntergatedCircuits/ARMed/blob/master/Memory-Access/BitBanding.md) to explain what bit-banding is, how it works and how to use it. I believe it answers most questions about bit-banding, feel free to (re)view it.

Comment: This is a handy introduction about bit-banding feature in ARM Cortex M3 https://atadiat.com/en/articles/e-bit-banding-explained-a-feature-of-arm-cortex-m3/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The [ARM info center](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp) refers to bit-banding in their Cortex-M3 and -M4 documentation, compiler docs, and a few other places, like [*Home > Programmers Model > Bit-banding*](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dai0179b/CHDJHIDF.html). From [*Home > Developing software for Cortex-M3 > Bit-banding*](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dai0179b/CHDJHIDF.html):

> Bit-banding maps a complete word of memory onto a single bit in the
>   bit-band region. For example, writing to one of the alias words will
>   set or clear the corresponding bit in the bitband region.

It appears to be a way to get single bit atomic operation.

> When writing to the alias regions bit 0 of the 32 bit word is used to
>   set the value at the bit-banding region. Reading from the alias
>   address will return the value from the bit-band region in bit 0 and
>   the other bits will be cleared.

Comment: Do you have any idea how bit-banded operations are performed internally, and what the real guarantees are with regard to atomicity?  Were I designing a chip to facilitate atomic bit-set or bit-clear operations, I would use two of the upper address bits to select between 'normal access' (00), 'write ones' (01), and 'write zeroes' (1x).  In addition, I'd have the CPU invert its data output when those address bits were 0x11.  In that way, bits could be set or cleared in one cycle, without need for a read-modify-write.  Even if bits would be set by hardware simultaneous with the write, ...

Comment: ...would not pose a problem.  As it is, I really don't know what would happen if someone did a bit-banded clear on something like an I/O device status location at the same time as hardware was causing another bit to become set.

Comment: AFAIK 1. Reading data using that alias isn't more atomic than simply reading the actual memeory. 2. Writing of a bit cannot be truly atomic. In either case. So what is the real benefit of this technology???

Comment: @AlKepp, Writing a bit on many of the systems I have used is truly atomic with a single instruction to perform the act that cannot be interrupted.

Comment: From DDI0337I page 3-16: "The System bus interface contains logic that controls bit-band accesses as follows: [...] For writes, it converts the write to an atomic read-modify-write operation."

Comment: @Kortuk: I work with generic multi-core systems with external memory controllers. It is hard to keep it truly atomic, when you need read-modify-write operation because of the granularity of memory is higher than number of bits you actually need to write.

Comment: @AlKepp, I was not trying to imply that there were systems that could not do this with an atomic instruction. You said, "Writing of a bit cannot be truly atomic." I was disagreeing with this claim. I have used many systems where it is atomic and they do exist.

Comment: @Kortuk: I understand your point - it may be atomic on simple computer systems. But I teach Operating Systems Principles courses in Computer science studies. I always see it more general - for example if you connect an external device with direct memory access, it breaks your so called "atomicity", because it is not a real atomicity. It is atomic only when you take memory controller and CPU/ALU core together as a "black-box" and there is no parallelism involved.

Comment: @AlKepp, The Cortex M3 is an example of more of a microcontroller. The importance to me is that you cannot say atomic instructions dont exist if they often do. Many people here do embedded systems that are low enough resource that the memory is internal, it is actually the only system I enjoy coding on. That aside, telling someone it does not exist when it does and is commonly used can mislead.

Comment: So then bit-banding allows you to set the state or read the state of as many as 32 uC pins at once?

Comment: @kurtnelle, No, it returns only either a 0x00000001 or 0x00000000, which can be useful. For example, to use directly in logic checks without preprocessing. (Eg. 0x00000010 would be FALSE if read from the bit-band alias region, but TRUE if pulled from elsewhere.) Note that I haven't actually used it, and, unbelievably, have been mistaken before.

Comment: @AlKepp: There are a variety of ways by which one could construct a memory system with truly atomic bit-set and bit-clear primitives which did not require read-modify-write cycles.  Perhaps the simplest approach would be for the memory array to have separate "write-AND" and "write-OR".  Normally, a memory write enables both high-side and low-side column drivers (so as to be able to write both ones and zeores), but if one enabled only one type of driver, one could selectively set or clear any combination of bits using a single cycle.